# How can i make a backslash for change line with peg.js?

Tags: peg, pegjs

Currently, I use '\n' to split each line (paragraph), but now, I want to make a backslash like python for change line.

This is my current rule:

```
Start
    = _ head:Line tail:('\n'+ l:Line { return l })* _ {
        return [head].concat(tail)
    }

Line = (!'\n' .)+ { return { lines: [ text() ] } }

_ = [ \n\r\t]*
```

Input:

```
This is Line 1

This is \ Line
\ 2
```

Current Output:

```js
[
   {
      "lines": [
         "This is Line 1"
      ]
   },
   {
      "lines": [
         "This is \ Line"
      ]
   },
   {
      "lines": [
         "\ 2"
      ]
   }
]
```

Expect Output:

```js
[
   {
      "lines": [
         "This is Line 1"
      ]
   },
   {
      "lines": [
         "This is",
         "Line",
         "2"
      ]
   },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I have make it come true by myself, this is my code:

```
{
  var lines = [];
  var lineText = "";
  function resetLines() {
    lines = [];
    lineText = "";
  }
}

Start
  = _ head:Line tail:("\n"+ l:Line { return l; })* _ {
      return [head].concat(tail);
    }

Line
  = ResetLines
    chars:(
      "\n"? "\\" "\n"? {
          lines.push(lineText);
          lineText = "";
        }
      / !"\n" . { lineText += text(); }
    )+ {
      lines.push(lineText);
      return lines;
    }

ResetLines = &" "* { (lines = []), (lineText = ""); }

_ = [ \n\r\t]*
```

Input:

```
This is Line 1

This is\Line
\2

This is Line 3
```

Output:

```js
[
   [
      "This is Line 1"
   ],
   [
      "This is",
      "Line",
      "2"
   ],
   [
      "This is Line 3"
   ]
]
```